# Setup multiple page headers at once with array VBA

Tags: vba

Here is where i get the error.

Any ideas?

```
Application.Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2")).PageSetup.RightHeader = "HELLO"
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: There are things that can not be done in array and must be done one by one through a loop.

Comment: Mhm i thought that

Answer (score 0):

Something on the order of

```
Option Explicit

Sub aa()
    Dim str As Variant
    For Each str In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
        Application.Sheets(str).PageSetup.RightHeader = "HELLO"
    Next str
End Sub
```

Comment: Very elegant! Thank you